# My observable List stores same value for all objects

Tags: java, mysql

```
ObservableList<Employee> employee = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                Employee newEmployee = new Employee(
                        resultSet.getString("eName1"),
                        resultSet.getString("eName2"),
                        resultSet.getString("eType"),
                        resultSet.getString("phoneNumber"),
                        resultSet.getInt("eSalary"),
                        resultSet.getDate("birthday").toLocalDate(),
                        resultSet.getString("password"),
                        resultSet.getBoolean("admin"));
                newEmployee.setEId(resultSet.getInt("eId"));
                newEmployee.setImageFile(new File(resultSet.getString("imageFile")));

                System.out.println(newEmployee);
                employee.add(newEmployee);
                System.out.println(employee);
        }
```

The result of the code above is below:

```
Frank Seo is 34 years old
[Frank Seo is 34 years old]
admin test is 27 years old
[admin Seo is 34 years old, admin test is 27 years old]
NotAdmin Test is 26 years old
[NotAdmin Seo is 34 years old, NotAdmin test is 27 years old, NotAdmin Test is 26 years old]
[NotAdmin Seo is 34 years old, NotAdmin test is 27 years old, NotAdmin Test is 26 years old]
```

This is the Employee constructor:

```
private static  int eId;
public Employee(String eName1, String eName2, String eType, String phoneNumber, int eSalary, LocalDate birthday, String password, boolean admin) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        setEName1(eName1);
        setEName2(eName2);
        setEType(eType);
        setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        setESalary(eSalary);
        setBirthday(birthday);
        setImageFile(new File("./src/Images/EmlpoyeeIcon.png"));
        salt = PasswordGenerator.getSalt();
        this.password = PasswordGenerator.getSHA512Password(password, salt);
        this.setAdmin(admin);
    }
```

I excluded eId from the construcotr as it auto increments in the database.
Why does objects' eName1 equal to each other?

This is the data I'm using.
[image]

Comment: check the meaning of `static` (fields) - Java Language Specification [8.3.1.1. static Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1) ((I can't see how the names are declared, so it is just a guess))

Comment: thank you... I didn't pay attention to the type..